# event time not properly displaying in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

event time not properly displaying in fullcalendar when time zone is (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London. so what should i do for this?? can ignoretimezone is helpfull for me??

Answer (score 0):

the allDay property needs to be set to `false` (the boolean, not the string) on each event object.